# new cygwinshell in own window

Tags: shell, cygwin

How can I start a second cygwin shell from commandline of the first cygwinshell which opens in a separate window?
I tried
"bash --login -i"
but it apparently it started in the current window.

Comment: Have you checked out `screen`? I use that to have multiple windows running - both in Cyg and Linux distros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by shell window. If it's the default setup, then it uses `cmd.exe`, so you can issue:

```
cygstart "/cygdrive/C/windows/system32/cmd.exe \k 'bash.exe -i'"
```

Or maybe simply this should work:

```
cygstart bash
```

Another working solution is (somewhat funny):

```
cmd /c start cmd /k 'bash -i'
```

But a recommended solution is to use something better (e.g. [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), rxvt (part of cygwin...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! "shell window" sould mean: A new interactive window opens in MS Windows containing a new cygwin shell and the old one which was used to launch the new one is still there and not blocked.

"cygstart bash" seems to be the solution, the other ones do not open a separate independent window.